# Starting a process (sudo start) on boot up

Tags: boot, configuration, init

So once I log into my Ubuntu VM I launch my application by doing a

```
sudo app
```

Now I want my application to get started while booting. I tried it by creating an `rc.` script but nothing seems to work. Can someone point me to the correct way of getting it done?

Also my application has to run `sudo`. Hoping auto start will have the runlevel as root

Comment: Is this a GUI or CLI application?

Comment: Its a C program... i just want to launch a binary.. like "a.out"

Comment: So have you tried editing `/etc/rc.local` (`sudo nano /etc/rc.local`) and adding your command before the line containing `exit 0`? You don't need `sudo` here because all commands in this file are executed as root by default.

Comment: Thanks .. i added this to rc.local. 
/path_to_script/run.sh 
exit(0)

It doe not come up on bootup, but after the bootup if i do a 
sudo ./rc.local.. it works.

What am i doing wrong ?

Comment: File names are really important here. Are you sure you've editted `/etc/rc.local`? Also, you **don't** put `exit 0` yourself there, but you put your command **above** the `exit 0` that's already there.

Answer (score 0):

You can try it with [Upstart](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/) (`/etc/rc.local` doesn't work for me either).

Example:

```
author "Your name goes here - optional"
description "What your daemon does shortly - optional"

start on started dbus
stop on stopping dbus

# console output  # if you want daemon to spit its output to console... ick
respawn # it will respawn if crashed/killed

script
   echo "Hello world!" > /home/username/test.txt # without root permissions
   sudo -u root fdisk -l > /home/username/fdisk.txt # with root permissions
end script
```

You would put that in `/etc/init/myUpStart.conf`.

Further details:

- [Running commands on boot in 11.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/96011/running-commands-on-boot-in-11-10)
- [How do I  start jobs as a non privileged user in Upstart?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/87671/how-do-i-start-jobs-as-a-non-privileged-user-in-upstart)
- [Run a Job as a Different User](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#run-a-job-as-a-different-user)