# Ubuntu 14 Upstart, Script Never Runs -- No Log File

Tags: upstart, nano

I apologize ahead of time if this has been answered, but Ive looked through all the other questions and havent found anything that helps.

Here is my upstart script:

nodeapps.conf

```
start on [2345]
forever start --spinSleepTime 10000 /home/nodeapps/node_app.js
forever start --spinSleepTime 10000 /home/nodeapps/node_metrix.js
```

When I reboot, I call `forever list` to see anything running. Nothing shows up.
The other answers I have seen suggest looking in /var/log/upstart, but there is no log for nodeapps.

I have tried start on startup, and start on [2345]

Am I missing something obvious? I created the file in /etc/init/, using nano.

Edit: I should note, this is Ubuntu 14 through a VPS, I only have console access, no gui.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this upstart script:

===

start on runlevel [2345]

exec start-stop-daemon --start --exec /usr/bin/forever -- start --spinSleepTime 10000 /home/nodeapps/node_app.js

exec start-stop-daemon --start --exec /usr/bin/forever -- start --spinSleepTime 10000  /home/nodeapps/node_metrix.js

===

Basically `forever` is not a keyword for an upstart script and upstart doesn't know what to do with it.

`exec` however is a keyword and it tells upstart which program to start.

UPDATE: Answers

`...do you think I could get away with just using /usr/bin/forever ....?` Most likely not. The upstart scripts are not a sequence of commands like bash scripts (or .bat / .cmd files in Windows). They are configuration files (like .ini files in Windows) and one of the configuration options happens to point to an actual executable.

`...does this explain the fact that theres no logfile being created?` Since forever has never been started it didn't have a chance to leave a log file behind. I am reasonably sure you could find something in the upstart log files though.

Comment: I will try this tomorrow, but it seems like it should work. It didn't cross my mind that forever might not be recognized.
Rather than using exec, do you think I could get away with just using `/usr/bin/forever ....`?
Also, does this explain the fact that theres no logfile being created?

Comment: `upstart scripts are not a sequence of commands like bash scripts` but you can use it like this http://askubuntu.com/a/459988/265974 (script tags) then you could work like in a bash script. But to run a daemon smurf answer should be the right way.

Comment: I do not think you can run two exec's like that. You need two jobs.

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm a bit late to this, but rather than using exec and the start-stop-daemon process, use forever's built in daemon, foreverd.

```
foreverd start --spinSleepTime 10000 /home/nodeapps/node_app.js
foreverd start --spinSleepTime 10000 /home/nodeapps/node_metrix.js
```

If the root env does not have a path to forever (though it probably does, because you installed it through sudo npm install -g forever) you need to specify the path to foreverd rather than running foreverd. Run

```
which foreverd
```

in a terminal that you've logged in to to get the location of foreverd, then run

```
/path/to/foreverd start --spinSleepTime 10000 /home/nodeapps/node_app.js
/path/to/foreverd start --spinSleepTime 10000 /home/nodeapps/node_metrix.js
```

This will also automatically create forever log files in ~/.forever/.log

you can figure out what  is by running forever list, which will give an output like this:

```
jbarber$ forever list
info:    Forever processes running
data:        uid  command             script                                              forever pid  logfile                         uptime       
data:    [0] 4Ola /usr/local/bin/node /home/jbarber/projects/project_name/_stage/index.js 7665    7667 /home/jbarber/.forever/4Ola.log 0:0:6:16.714
```

You can then restart/stop the process using

```
foreverd restart <process_num>
foreverd stop <process_num>
```

in this example process num would be 0.