# upstart starts python script but it behaves unexpectedly

Tags: python, upstart

The program works when started by `cron` or from the shell. But when started by `upstart`, it seems to loop indefinitely.

The scripts and the files they use are in the `/home/user/` directory, and are owned by `user`, and all have `777` permissions.

**The upstart .conf file:**

```
start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [!2345]

kill signal SIGHUP
# reload signal SIGHUP
respawn

exec python /home/user/Documents/init.py -b 600
```

Answer (score 1):

`upstart` executes commands as root by default. But the user can be specified: [How do I  start jobs as a non privileged user in Upstart?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/87671/how-do-i-start-jobs-as-a-non-privileged-user-in-upstart).

But the script was programmed with user specific variables and a dependency to a specific directory.

`init.py` had this line:

```
self.d_root = os.path.join(os.path.expanduser('~'),'Documents','records')
```

I changed it to this and it worked:

```
self.d_root = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
```

But I think the proper fix is to add this line to the `.conf` file:

```
setuid = user
```